# How does statsmodels calculate in-sample predictions in AR models?

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels

I am very new to time series modeling and statsmodels and trying to understand the AR model in statsmodels. Suppose I have a data record `y` of 1000 samples, and I fit an AR (1) model on `y`. Then I generate the in-sample prediction from this model as `y_pred`. I do this as

```
from statsmodels.tsa.ar_model import AutoReg
model = AutoReg(y,1).fit()
y_pred = model.predict()
```

I get the parameters of the model using `model.params`.

I would like to know, after estimating the model parameters, how does statsmodels calculate the in-sample predictions? For ex. how is `y_pred[10]` calculated?

I am sorry if the question is too basic, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model):

> The autoregressive model specifies that the output variable depends linearly on its own previous values and on a stochastic term (an imperfectly predictable term).

In your model example, you have one predictor - lagged value of `y`. In this simple case, the `.predict()` method multiplies each lagged value by the value of the estimated linear slope parameter for that predictor and adds the estimated value of the intercept of that line. So `y_pred[10]` will be equal to the product of the fitted slope parameter and `y[9]`, with the value of the intercept estimate added.

Here is an example:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.ar_model import AutoReg

y = [1, 2, 3, 6, 2, 9, 1]

model = AutoReg(y,1).fit()
model.params
# array([ 5.72953737, -0.49466192])
```

The first value in the `params` array is the estimated intercept parameter and the second value is the estimated linear (slope) parameter.

```
y_pred = model.predict()
y_pred
# array([5.23487544, 4.74021352, 4.2455516 , 2.76156584, 4.74021352, 1.27758007])
```

The first value in the `y_pred` array is the predicted value for the second value in the `y` array.  It is calculated as:

```
-0.49466192 * 1 + 5.72953737 = 5.23487544
```

The second value in the `y_pred` array is computed as:

```
-0.49466192 * 2 + 5.72953737 = 4.74021353
```

and so on...

Comment: Thanks! Is this a 1-step ahead prediction? If yes, how do I make a k-step ahead prediction? And how does statsmodels calculate that?

Comment: @ChandramouliSanthanam Yes, this is a 1-step ahead prediction, meaning that each prediction is calculated using just the previous value in the sequence (as shown above).  For k-step ahead predictions, are you asking how to predict for multiple out-of-sample steps with this AR model?  This model will continue to use either a previous value you provide in the original sequence or will take the previous predicted value as input if the true value is not available.  That's a recursive strategy for multi-step forecasting.

Comment: @ChandramouliSanthanam It is also possible to create a model or models to directly forecast each k step, but that requires a different set-up.  You can look for material explaining recursive vs. direct strategies.

Comment: Actually, I was asking about predicting multiple in-sample steps with this AR model. So when I mean a 'k-step ahead prediction' (not a forecast), I mean to predict the value of `y[t]` using the in- samples `y[0], y[1], ...y[t-k]` only. The values at time instances `t-k+1,...t-p` will then be predicted using the AR(p) model and be subsequently used to predict `y[t]`. So in this case the AR(p) model predicts k steps with the ultimate goal of predicting `y[t]`.  
MATLAB has an argument called Prediction Horizon for this

Comment: In statsmodels, you can specify specific lag values in the `lags=` parameter of `AutoReg()`.  So if `lags=[2,3]`, the model will not use lag=1 for fitting the model. Using your notation, `k` is 1 in this example.  AR(p) model does not, in general, predict k steps. It just uses lagged values specified by one or more `p` parameter values to predict each individual step.  (You can see the model definition equation on the Wikipedia page).  If this still does not answer your question, please post a separate question on SO and/or consult the documentation.